# postgres not deploying on heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

I am attempting to connect my RDS postgres db over to Heroku. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but every time I use heroku, my old sqlite3 db keeps getting used. Locally my postgres db works fine, but it's not deploying on heroku. I am using dj_database url. I've gone through and made sure my database settings matched what I have on heroku over and over, and I'm still not sure why it's not pushing to Heroku.

**traceback**

```
2020-07-11T19:26:13.248140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:13 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:26:13.320264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:26:24.501196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:26:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-11T19:26:27.286692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:26:27.287606+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14756 (4)
2020-07-11T19:26:27.287746+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:26:27.293342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:26:27.343582+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:26:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-11T19:26:27.851588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-11T19:26:59.695073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=cupids-corner.herokuapp.com request_id=f5dd71c5-d6a5-4a06-8d8e-b506859c933a fwd="100.36.43.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-07-11T19:27:00.453216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:27:00 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
2020-07-11T19:27:01.464739+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:27:01 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
2020-07-11T19:29:18.266925+00:00 app[api]: Release v77 created by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:18.266925+00:00 app[api]: Remove DATABASE_URL config vars by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:18.642733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-07-11T19:29:18.654156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-07-11T19:29:20.114791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T19:29:20.154180+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:20 -0400] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
2020-07-11T19:29:20.155794+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:20 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T19:29:20.159258+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T19:29:20.257065+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:29:20.343634+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:29:21.811888+00:00 app[api]: Release v78 created by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:21.811888+00:00 app[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:23.059673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-07-11T19:29:28.210410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:29:30.070467+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:29:30.071054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29527 (4)
2020-07-11T19:29:30.071160+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:29:30.075339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:29:30.144814+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:30 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-11T19:29:31.175076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T19:29:31.203882+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:31 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T19:29:31.204310+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T19:29:31.204311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:31 -0400] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-07-11T19:29:31.304852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:29:31.389352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:29:33.605449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:29:35.686242+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:29:35.686798+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:18649 (4)
2020-07-11T19:29:35.686918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:29:35.690770+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:35 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:29:35.717528+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:35 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-11T19:29:35.746321+00:00 app[api]: Remove DATABASE_URL config vars by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:35.746321+00:00 app[api]: Release v79 created by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:35.798708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-11T19:29:36.594691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-07-11T19:29:36.607908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-07-11T19:29:37.305963+00:00 app[api]: Release v80 created by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:37.305963+00:00 app[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:37.529577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T19:29:37.557612+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T19:29:37.557644+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:37 -0400] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-07-11T19:29:37.557800+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:37 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T19:29:37.658117+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:29:37.723003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:29:37.726220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-07-11T19:29:46.309454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:29:47.301312+00:00 app[api]: Release v81 created by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:47.301312+00:00 app[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2020-07-11T19:29:47.523466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:29:47.857179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-07-11T19:29:48.340854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:29:48.341491+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:44163 (4)
2020-07-11T19:29:48.341618+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:29:48.345653+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:29:48.445622+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:48 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2020-07-11T19:29:49.699615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T19:29:49.736903+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:49 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T19:29:49.737269+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T19:29:49.737373+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:49 -0400] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2020-07-11T19:29:49.837631+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:29:49.909420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:29:49.923941+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:29:49.924487+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:28971 (4)
2020-07-11T19:29:49.924586+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:29:49.928891+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:29:49.931500+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:49 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-11T19:29:51.034436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T19:29:51.080195+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:51 -0400] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-07-11T19:29:51.080236+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T19:29:51.081422+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 15:29:51 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T19:29:51.181003+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:29:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T19:29:51.237472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-07-11T19:29:59.954021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dating_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-07-11T19:30:02.457037+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:30:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-07-11T19:30:02.457662+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:30:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4135 (4)
2020-07-11T19:30:02.457742+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:30:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-07-11T19:30:02.462351+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:30:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-07-11T19:30:02.493543+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 19:30:02 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-07-11T19:30:03.007273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-11T20:02:10.400956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-07-11T20:02:10.403216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-07-11T20:02:12.198104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-11T20:02:12.267882+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 16:02:12 -0400] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-07-11T20:02:12.320113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 16:02:12 -0400] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-07-11T20:02:12.347672+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 20:02:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-07-11T20:02:12.451184+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-11 20:02:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-07-11T20:02:12.705666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'cupids-corner',
        'USER': 'rezazandi',
        'PASSWORD': '***********',
        'HOST' : 'cupids-corner.cp5uqhct8bo1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT' : '5432'
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

**heroku.com/config_vars**

```
Key: DATABSE_URL
Value: postgres://rezazandi:(password)@cupids-corner.cp5uqhct8bo1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/cupids-corner
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that I had to go into my RDS on AWS and change my inbound rules to allow ALL connections. After that, it worked.